# How to remove `\centering` tag from a figure block in LaTeX generated from pandoc?

Tags: pdf-generation, markdown, pandoc

When generating a PDF from markdown using pandoc, the markdown is converted into LaTeX. I am using a customized template to style my PDF.

When I create an image link:

```
![Alt text](image.png)
```

the following LaTeX is generated.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{Alt text}
\end{figure}
```

The image is, not surprisingly, centered on the PDF.

How do I prevent the `\centering` tag from being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can't, but if your document does not use `\centering` for any other purpose, you can redefine it at as "void" (`\relax`) before it is used. You can do this in several ways:

- Include the line `\def\centering{\relax}` at the beginning of your pandoc document. Pandoc passes all latex code "as is" to the resulting `.tex` file.
- Modify your latex template and include the definition of `\centering` at the appropiate point (for example, just before `\begin{document}`
- If you are using pandoc's standard template, you can still insert code into it at compile-time, using pandoc's `--variable` option to define the variable `header-includes`. For example:

  ```
  pandoc -s --variable:header-includes="\\def\\centering{\\relax}" yourdoc.markdown -o yourdoc.tex
  ```

Comment: For my purposes, this worked like a charm. Thanks! You are correct, if `\centering` is used anywhere, it will redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

The @JLDiaz answer does not work for me because I want to use `\centering` command. Therefore I created [Lua filter](https://gist.github.com/flat35hd99/e7ea6630a6ef71b0adbfe72c2138e9be)

```lua
function Image(elem)
    local src = pandoc.utils.stringify(elem.src)

    local alt = ''
    for i, v in ipairs(elem.caption) do
        if v == nil or v.text == nil then
            goto continue
        end
        
        if v.t == 'Math' then
            alt = alt .. ' \\(' .. v.text .. '\\)'
        else
            alt = alt .. ' ' .. v.text
        end
        ::continue::
    end

    if elem.attr.identifier == '' then
        return pandoc.RawInline('latex',
               '\\begin{figure}\n'
            .. '\\includegraphics{' .. src .. '}\n'
            .. '\\caption{' .. alt .. '}\n'
            .. '\\end{figure}\n'
        )
    end

    return
        pandoc.RawInline('latex',
               '\\begin{figure}\n'
            .. '\\hypertarget{' .. elem.attr.identifier .. '}{%\n'
            .. '\\includegraphics{' .. src .. '}\n'
            .. '\\caption{' .. alt .. '}\n\\label{' .. elem.attr.identifier .. '}\n'
            .. '}\n'
            .. '\\end{figure}\n'
        )
end
```

You can use this script by:

```
pandoc -s \
  --lua-filter uncentering-figures.lua \
  -o output.pdf \
  input.md
```

and this script can be used with pandoc-crossref:

```
pandoc -s \
  --lua-filter uncentering-figures.lua \
  --filter pandoc-crossref \
  -o output.pdf \
  input.md
```

I hope this snippet helps someone like me.